# How can myocyte contract in "isovolumetric contraction" phase of cardiac cycle without shortening?

Tags: physiology, cardiac-physiology

What is the difference between a contraction that shortens the muscle and generates force and the isovolumetric contraction that generates force with shortening the muscle??

Answer (score 1):

Isovolumetric contraction of heart is a type of isometric contraction of muscles because something is resisting applying the equal and opposite force, in case of heart it is the blood which is applying opposite pressure thus increasing the pressure inside heart and volume remaining constant because the valves are closed as the same way you can push a wall but it won’t move but the muscles will be in tension as the wall is applying an equal and opposite force.

You can imagine it like this suppose myosin is pulling actin fibres towards the center of sarcomere but the equal and opposite force is resisting it